# German Books in Qualitative ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

Can anyone refer to me some good german books on introductory, qualitative ODE that cover topics like Picard-Lindelof, Peano's Existence Theorem?

Answer (score 1):

Wolfgang Walter, "Gewöhnliche Differentialgleichungen"

http://books.google.ch/books/about/Gew%C3%B6hnliche_Differentialgleichungen.html?id=tyAdMH69NRYC&redir_esc=y